# How to make 9 slides from 3 slides on mobile devices with fullpage.js?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fullpage.js

I designed whole website with FullPage.js, after I finished my work I need to make it responsive. So, the problem is at section with slides, there is 3 slides with 3 elements on each slide. Now I need to make one slide from each element without copy code. It looks like this:

Desktop ->
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBgjz.jpg

What I need on mobile ->
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufiST.jpg

I tried to add class to each element, then show it on mobile and hide desktop class. But it doesn't work.

```html
<div class="slide fp-auto-height" data-anchor="slide1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.box {
  background: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

In brief, I want to shown 3 elements on each slide on computer, and 1 element on each slide on mobile. I mean on mobile each element must be adapted to viewport of device, not shown by scrolling.

Comment: I highly suggest looking into "flexbox"

Comment: Yes, but with flexbox my elements descend. I need to keep fullpage.js features, so each element must be shown in height and width of actually mobile viewport... But thanks for suggest.

Comment: Should the elements slide to on mobile? In general you can style your slider in a way to cut of the other elements on mobile.

Comment: Not easy. That would imply destroying and initializing fullpage.js again I would suggest you to get rid of the horizontal slides and just convert them into vertical sections.  You can easily do that by using the [Responsive Slides extension of fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/responsive-slides.html).

Comment: Thank you guys. It's too complicated for me and I don't have time for it - so i decide to make separated page for mobile devices with redirect.